# PHP DomDocument alter conditional comments

Tags: php, html, dom, document

I have this html file with a conditional comment.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/elements.css">
        <title>Page</title>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" />
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
etc...
```

I am using the DomDocument library to modify the `<link>` attributes. Is there any way of getting DomDocument to read and modify the `<link>` element in the conditional comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('head') as $head) {
    foreach($head->childNodes as $node) {
        if($node instanceof DOMComment) {
            $node->replaceData(16,60,'test');
        }
    }
}
```

This code works, I just let you search how to get 'offset' and 'count' value for the replaceData method !

Comment: It's incredible that I could not find anything on the internet ! I hope it will help other people ^^

Comment: Is there a way of getting getElementsByTagName to pick up tags in comments as well?  It's not ideal to loop through all child nodes to find those within comments.