# Xpath to select commented code

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have this xpath query:

```
descendant-or-self::link
```

and this html code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/elements.css">
<title>Page</title>
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
etc...
```

What do I need to add to this query to make it also match the commented `<link>`.

This is a continuation of this question: 
[PHP DomDocument alter conditional comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879108/php-domdocument-alter-conditional-comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the union operator "|":

descendant-or-self::link|/*/comment()

This will return the text of the comment, which cannot be used for further parsing even though it contains markup-like text. It's just a string so you'll have to treat it like one.

Answer (score 4):

In XPath 1.0, with proper XHTML:

```
/xhtml:html/xhtml:head/xhtml:link|
/xhtml:html/xhtml:head/comment()[contains(.,'link')]
```

With a DOM provider that it doesn't handle namespaces:

```
/html/head/link|
/html/head/comment()[contains(.,'link')]
```

Also:

```
/html/head/node()[self::link or self::comment()[contains(.,'link')]]
```

Comment: Ok, will I be able to treat it as a normal node or does it just return a text value?

Comment: @Franky Chanyau: It returns two `link` elements and one comment node. Then you could manipulate the comment string value.