# Including tags in conditional comments when using getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, domdocument

I would like to use getElementsByTagName to find all **script** tags in my HTML and then work with the src attribute.

I have this working fine with the following code, but it ignores  tags inside conditional comments.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $node) 
{
    if ($node->hasAttribute('src'))
    {
        echo $node->getAttribute('src');
    } 
}
```

Example of conditional comment tag getting ignored:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there any way to include this in the search as well?  I found the thread below but the suggestion to loop through all child elements isn't exactly ideal.  Are they are any other solutions?

[PHP DomDocument alter conditional comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879108/php-domdocument-alter-conditional-comments)

Thanks everso!

Comment: Could you elaborate on, "ignores tags inside conditional comments"?

Comment: I've edited the question to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

A comment is a comment, so what’s in there does *not* generate a `script` element in the DOM. No element == nothing to select.

If you don’t like the solution from the other thread, then you could try and cut out the comments with regular expressions before creating the DOM object. But if that’s more reliable is to be doubted … encounter f.e. any slightly malformed HTML, and that might cut out more (or less) than you expected.

Comment: OK, Thought that was what was being said... Could OP not write conditionals so that `src` is appended in either case, and rather using the conditional to set an actual value or null?  Or since `src` means something use a second user defined attribute?

Comment: I've updated my question to include an example of what I mean.  In my case I'm talking specifically about conditional comments.  I was using regular expressions previously but DOMDocument is always recommended ahead of this.

Comment: I got what you meant – but as I said, there __is no script element__ when that code gets transformed into a DOM by a normal DOM parser. A comment is a comment is a comment – and MicroSoft are the only people in the world who (idiotically) thought otherwise.

Comment: I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't require parsing HTML with regex.  My code works using regex but it is widely considered unreliable for this, so I am investigating the best way of doing this with DOMDocument.  Looping through childelements for an entire HTML document clearly isn't the best method, hence asking it anyone knew of anything else...

Comment: Well, you don’t have to loop through the _whole_ document – since a valid HTML document will not have more than one `head` element. (And the code in the answer to the other question will “loop” only once through the outer loop for that reason as well.)